# Javascript autocomplete function failure

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

i have an aspx web forms page from which i wish to use autocomplete using data from a database. the problem is that the response i am getting is rather web page html and not the database data. i have placed a breakpoint on the web method in the aspx.cs that executes the data fetching from the database but it doesnt hit meaning that probably the javascript is not invoking this method at all. however, execution of the autocomplete also logs a dummy message in the console which i set to print in the event of an error in the javascript execution. below is the code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Hello World :)");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id$=txtbxClassTeacher]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Controllers/Videos/GetTeacherName/",
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(Jscript Successful");
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log("jscript error");
                            console.log(response);
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            console.log("jscript failure");
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });

</script>
```

then the web method:

```
public class VideosController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public static List<string> GetTeacherName(string teacherName)
    {
        List<string> myResult = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 25 Name FROM dbo.Profiles WHERE Level=19 AND Name LIKE ''+@SearchTeacherName+'%'";
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTeacherName", teacherName);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        myResult.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return myResult;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return myResult;
        }
    }
}
```

then the textbox which implements the auto-complete:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-3 control-label">Class Teacher</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbxClassTeacher" placeholder="Class Teacher" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control"/>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbxClassTeacher" ErrorMessage="This field cannot be empty!"  CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

thank you for the assistance

Comment: The JSON body you're posting to Controllers/Videos/GetTeacherName/ only defines a value for "prefix", but GetTeacherName is only defined to take a parameter called "teacherName". Also I'd consider using GET for this sort of lookup.

Comment: sorry can you explain a bit what you mean. my small mind cant figure what you mean exactly. in my mind the web method is suppose to take one argument, "teacherName" from the javascript json body which is the "prefix" value. when i changed the json body from "prefix" to "teacherName" it still behaved the same way as before, so my question is, how should i address that

Comment: Hmm, I'd think that would work, but try Controllers/Videos/GetTeacherName?teacherName=xxxx

Comment: still same result, but why isnt my breakpoint hitting. dont you think the method is not being invoked at all, its not running at all. a close look at the returned html file shows me that its returning my default error handling page for error 404

Comment: Correct, the method's not being invoked. Something's not right with your route mapping.